# I am getting doubts in android button clicking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, button, android-button

Hi in my code i have two activity in first activity there is two buttons one is visible another is invisible if i click first button second button have to visible and i have to go next activity on that activity there is one button if click that button it have to come first activity now second button have to display first button have to invisible please help me.

## mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.mypratic;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button frst,scnd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frst=(Button)findViewById(R.id.firstbtn);
        scnd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scndbtn);
        frst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                frst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## mainactivity2.java

```
package com.example.admin.mypratic;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.third);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at android messages between activities

Comment: sorry i am not getting

Comment: @chandu, what is your current result? What are you getting in your first activity when you are returning from second activity? Do you want to see button 2 instead of button 1?

Comment: yes i want second button instated of first button

Comment: call finish() in onClick method of  b3.setOnClickListener rather than starting a new Intent

Comment: i tried but its not working @raghavendra

Comment: Remove  finish(); in frst.setOnClickListener...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see button 2 instead of button 1 when you are coming back from second activity, you don't start first activity rather you finish you current activity (MainActivity2) and android will pull first activity from the Intent stack. [Also, you don't finish first activity after the call from second activity to hold it's status/state].
startActivity restart your activity, so the onCreate is fired and the default layout is loaded.

so the newly modified button codes:
in mainActivity1

```
frst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            frst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In second activity

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

needless to say, you need to have an onClickListener for your button 2, so that button 1 is visible for on click.

Cheers mate!

Comment: no it's not working if i click button 3 app is closing. if i click button 3 it want to come previous activity on this activity second button only display instated of third button

Comment: @chandu, I have changed both of your button code. (for button 1, 2 in acitivity 1) and button 3(for acitivty 3).

Comment: @chandu pls check the aa_oo solution properly. There is no finish() in frst.setOnClickListener impl.

Comment: if we have 3 activity where it will go

Comment: You will start another activity using Intent, it will go there. If you want to keep the state, you will use finish, if not you will restart you first activity using Intent i = new Intent(.......); @chandu